make data created with =SORTBY a table object
Is there a way to transform data created by a SORTBY function a table object?
I have data created with a formula
=SORTBY(OtherSheet!A1:C100,A1:A100)

(the syntax may be not perfect here but it is in my workbook).
and I would like it to be a Table object.
This is because I have a PivotTable based on this new data, and the PivotTable will only refresh automatically if based on a Table object, otherwise it requires a manual Refresh.
I cannot use VBA because it has to work in Excel for the web.
Any hint?
If I transform it into a Table object, it will SPILL...

I don't think it's doable without VBA but also not really necessary you can reference a spill array by using the spill range operator (#).

Short answer: NO.

Thanks @Michal, I will try referencing the spilled array like that as the Pivot source and see if it refreshes automatically

Inserting a pivot table for OtherSheet!A1:C100 would give the same result.

Also there's a function called PIVOTBY (or GROUPBY) which may do the same as you intend without the need of updating. Also your SORTBY formula could simply be =SORT(A1:C100)

If you want to use spill range for pivot table, you may want add it as a named range, for example sorted - refers to Sheet1!$D$2# then use it as the data source. When setting a spilled range as the source, range is set the spilled range at the time and does not change afterwards.

@Michal, the pivot does not allow me a souce =OtherSheet!A2#...

@nkalvi, neither it does using a named range... it loses the headers, since it considers the first line (row 2) as headers, and breaks on Refresh... maybe I will try =OtherSheet!A1# instead of A2#?

@CorradoBarbero, I've added a suggestion, though I would consider what P.b suggested first.

Here's one way to use SORTBY results for pivot table:

add column names to the SORTBY results:
=VSTACK(Table1[#Headers], SORTBY(Table1,Table1[Amt],-1))
In Name Manager, add a name for the spilled range:
sorted refers to =Sheet1!$D$2#
click inside the results range and add a pivot table and change the data source to sorted
pivot table needs to be refreshed after making changes to the source (OtherSheet!A1:C100,A1:A100 in your example), please




Many many thanks, @nkalvi, but this still does not solve my problem... the PivotTable needs to be manually refreshed... which in the end is the only thing I am trying to avoid...
I'll see if PIVOTBY will hep

You're most welcome. Pivot tables do not automatically refresh regardless of the source - you can add one to a table and see. Unless you need the other benefits of pivot tables, PIVOTBY  is good option.  PIVOTBY function - Microsoft Support

They DO refresh automatically if based on a table object... that's my whole point.

"By default, PivotTables are not refreshed automatically, but you can specify that the PivotTable is automatically refreshed when you open the workbook that contains the PivotTable." Refresh PivotTable data - Microsoft Support

I also don't find it in written, but I am quite sure I have one that refreshes automatically :-) I will look for it.

I solved my problem differently.
Since my PivotTable was actually a tabular format, I instead filled-up a table object with formulas so I could apply slicers and have the data refreshed automatically.
Thanks everybody!
